# MIPS Assembly - MARS li.s

Tags: assembly, mips, eclipse-mars

I am trying to use li.s in MARS MIPS Assembly for a two constants however I cannot get it to work as it gives me errors, what would the right way to implement these constants?

```
li.s $f2, 3.14159
li.s $f3, 64.0
```

Answer (score 0):

On MIPS CPUs (both real CPUs and simulators) the (integer) `li` instruction is just a shortcut for another instruction (or a set of two instructions!) doing that job: `li $a0, 0x12345678` actually means:

```
lui $a0, 0x1234
addiu $a0, $a0, 0x5678
```

Having a look at the floating point instruction set of MIPS CPUs I think this is not possible with floating point registers.

You'll have to store the floating point number in some memory location and use the `l.s` instruction to load the number from there.